# Alias scoping in bash functions

Tags: bash

I use a script (which I do not have write access to) that creates a bunch of aliases to set up  an environment. I would like to create a bash function to setup my environment, but it seems that the aliases do not survive to the function body.

Here's a minimal example:

```
# aliases.sh
alias fooAlias='echo "this will never work!"'
```

.

```
# .bashrc
function setupLotsOfThings() {
    source aliases.sh
    fooAlias
}
```

.

Now, if I simply source `aliases.sh` interactively, things work as expected:

```
[mycomputer]~/ $ source aliases.sh
[mycomputer]~/ $ fooAlias
this will never work!
```

However, if I instead call the function defined in my .bashrc, it doesn't recognize the alias after sourcing its definition:

```
[mycomputer]~/ $ setupLotsOfThings
-bash: fooAlias: command not found
```

What is going on here? Is there something I am missing about the scope of the `alias` command when used in a function?

**Edit:** I'll add some details beyond the minimal example to shine some light on what I'm trying to accomplish.

For my work I develop and run a lot of software on a cluster and/or grid. I have several projects that require completely different environments, such as different gcc versions, specific software releases, config and data PATHs, and various environment variables. Administrators provide the scripts to set up various things, usually by defining shell functions or aliases, which invoke other functions or aliases or run various scripts. To me, it's a black box.

I'd like to setup my own various environments with a single command. Currently, I do something like:

```
[mycomputer]~/ $ source /some/environment/setup/script.sh
[mycomputer]~/ $ aliasToSetupSomeSoftwareVersion    #this was defined in the above
[mycomputer]~/ $ anotherAliasForOtherSoftware
[mycomputer]~/ $ source /maybe/theres/another/script.sh
[mycomputer]~/ $ runSomeOtherSetup      # this was defined in the new script
```

These commands generally have to be run in order. My idea basically was to just copy the above lines into a function block, but as original example shows, that simply doesn't work. Alternative workarounds are more than welcome!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An alternative solution is to paste those commands into a text file instead of a function block. Something like:

```
## This is needed to make the sourced aliases available
## within the script.
shopt -s expand_aliases

source /some/environment/setup/script.sh
aliasToSetupSomeSoftwareVersion
anotherAliasForOtherSoftware
source /maybe/theres/another/script.sh
runSomeOtherSetup
```

Save that as `setup1.sh` wherever you like. The trick is to then *source* this file, not execute it:

```
$ source setup1.sh
```

That will run the aliases that are in the script and also make them available to your current shell.

You can further simplify the process by adding this to your `.bashrc`:

```
alias setupLotsOfThings="source setup1.sh"
```

*Now* you can simply run `setupLotsOfThings` and get the behavior you wanted from the function.

---

#### Explanation

There are two issues here. First, aliases are not available to the function they are declared in but only once that function has exited and second that aliases are not available within scripts. Both are explained in the same section of `man bash`:

> Aliases are not expanded when the shell is not interactive, unless 
>   the expand_aliases  shell option is set using shopt (see the
>   description of    shopt under SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS below).
>
> The rules concerning the definition and use  of  aliases  are 
>   somewhat    confusing.   Bash  always  reads  at  least  one complete
>   line of input    before executing any  of  the  commands  on  that 
>   line.   Aliases  are    expanded  when  a command is read, not when it
>   is executed.  Therefore,    an alias definition appearing on the same
>   line as another command  does    not  take  effect  until  the next
>   line of input is read.  The commands    following the alias definition
>   on that line are not affected by the new    alias.   This  behavior 
>   is  also an issue when functions are executed.    **Aliases are expanded
>   when a function definition is read, not  when  the   function  is 
>   executed,  because a function definition is itself a compound
>   command.  As a consequence, aliases defined in a function are not
>
>   available  until  after  that function is executed.**  To be safe,
>   always    put alias definitions on a separate line, and do not use
>   alias in  com‐    pound commands.

Then, there is the difference between executing and sourcing a file. Basically, running a script makes it run in a separate shell while sourcing it makes it run in the current shell. So, sourcing `setup.sh` makes the aliases available to the parent shell while executing it as a script would not.

Comment: Well, I'm working on a cluster, and have several such "aliasing" scripts available that help setup software environments, etc. The alias script defines many different aliases; my goal is to invoke a specific environment by sourcing the correct aliases, and then running (some of) those aliases. I'd rather do this in a single command, than have to run several commands in sequence.

Comment: And P.S. the script that sets up the aliases is unfortunately very verbose and a bit slow (as it touches many files on the NFS), so I prefer not to source all these things e.g. at login time.

Comment: @chase but they're only sourced when you run `setupLotsOfThings`, they're just not available to the function itself. They work o the shell you called the function from. Anyway, if your function only sources aliases why not just use an alias? For example: `alias setupstuff="source aliases.sh"`.

Comment: right, but I'm not worried about the scope _per se_. Ideally I just want to combine the "source stuff" and the "run aliases" step into one. Perhaps it can be done with 3 functions? function sourceStuff() { source ... }; function runStuff() { someAlias; ... }; function setupLotsOfThings() { sourceStuff; runStuff; };

Comment: @chase yeah, I thought of that but it didn't work :). Could you expand your question with some more of what you need to do? Functions can only deal with so much complexity, you might have to write a little script instead.

Comment: thanks for your interest! I was quite surprised when it didn't work the obvious way. I've edited the original post with more gory details.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, your aliases are available after the function is loaded! You can use them in your interactive shell, or in your `.bashrc` after executing the function.

The restriction is that aliases in a function definition are expanded when the function definition is read, not when the function is evaluated. This is a limitation of bash. So this will work:

```
function setupLotsOfThings() {
    source aliases.sh
}
setupLotsOfThings
fooAlias
```

But not this:

```
function setupLotsOfThings() {
    source aliases.sh
}
function useTheAliases() {
    fooAlias
}
setupLotsOfThings
useTheAliases
```

If you need aliases that are usable inside functions and can be defined after the function is parsed, make them functions instead. Remember that you can use the `command` builtin to invoke an external command from a function of the same name.